# See the version of Bash in the prompt

Tags: bash

When I open the terminal on the console I have `user@Sytem-Product-Name:-$` and at work when ever I type bash I get `bash 3.2$:` (or something very similar, Note I'm using putty on other unix distro) for commodity reasons (space).

I would like to see bash `4.2$` in my terminal. I've installed it and made the

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

on the directory I've extracted bash but can't seem to make the version appear on my console.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the value of the variable `PS1` on the bash config file:

1. Open (or create) the file `~/.bashrc`
2. At the end, add this line:

   ```
   PS1="bash \v\$ "
   ```
3. Save the file and open a terminal.